# PHP can I create an object of the class if I dynamically have access to the codes of class?

Tags: php, class

This is something weird but I want to create an object of a class that is stored in another file and I have the path to file but not the name of the class.
the scenario is, there are many files stored in a directory and every file contains one class only. out of this directory is another file in which I an developing a function that takes the name of file, access the file and fetch the codes out of it then create an object of the class in that file and return the object.
I am sure that it is possible but cant get it to work.
Can anybody help me ?

Comment: It's good practice to save class file names as the name of the class... you aren't doing that? Wouldn't that pretty much solve your problem?

Comment: amm.. ok, suppose the class name and the file name are same, then how would you do that ?

Answer (score 3):

Compare the results of [`get_declared_classes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php) before and after you include the file using [`array_diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php):

```
<?php

  $before = get_declared_classes();
  include_once('path/to/file');
  $after = get_declared_classes();

  $newClasses = array_diff($after, $before);

  for ($i = 0; isset($newClasses[$i]); $i++) {
    ${'class'.$i} = new $newClasses[$i];
    echo "New class $newClasses[$i] instantiated in variable \$class$i\n";
  }
```

Comment: In case OP has multiple classes per file (for whatever reason), this will find all of them. Good answer.

Comment: actually I need to instantiate the same class many times, does this function create an object of the correct class every time ?

Comment: It creates one instance of each class defined in the file that was included. If there is only one class in the file, it will create one instance in the variable `$class1`. If you need to create a new instance of the class for an object that you have, you can use [`get_class()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class.php) to get the name of the class. So for instance you could do `$className = get_class($class1); $newInstance = new $className;`. Or if you are 100% sure there is only one class in the file you included, you can bin the `for` loop and just do `$var = new $newClasses[0];`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`get_declared_classes()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-declared-classes.php)

E.g.:

```
$klass = end(get_declared_classes());
$obj = new $klass;
```

Comment: Removed downvote, converted to upvote. As an experienced SO user, escpecially replying to a user's first post hence setting an example, I find the link only answer with no explanation whatsoever a bit disappointing. This solution is good, hopefully OP is storing only a single class in each file...

Answer (score -1):

this is simple but not very secure.

1.Load the source file as text, match the content for a regexp that will return the name of the class in $classname.

2.Do any check you need to ensure this class is wanted in your "loading process" based on the source code text , like extracting constructor parameters.

1. require_once('the_file.php')
2. $my_new_instance=new $classname() (given you have no constructor parameters) or $my_new_instance=new $classname($param1,$param2) given you have extracted parameters $param1,$param2 from source analysis phase.

Comment: Yeah the regexp solution here is very very dirty, I would delete this.

Comment: the regexp solution allows to not include unwanted files if not necessary or potentially causing class redefinitions.but i agree, it's very bad practice.

Comment: It's really really dirty, slow (loading the whole file as text, parsing it with regex) and unreliable, plus you have not provided the regex, which is another point of contention.

Comment: since its problematic is "i don't know the code in the files", i cannot provide the regex for his particular use case

Comment: Exactly - there isn't one, or if there is, it's merit is debatable.

Comment: but blindly including files can also lead to problems.